# Does a corporation "do business" wherever its subsidiaries do?

Tags: internet, multiple-jurisdiction

Does a corporation fall under the jurisdiction of wherever its subsidiaries or affiliates do business? Consider there is no common branding and operations are separate .

Answer (score 1):

### No

Shareholders of a company (including corporate shareholders which is what the owner of a subsidiary is) are not the company.

Similarly, associated corporations (the definition for which varies by jurisdiction but generally involves some level of joint control or decision making) are legally distinct entities.

Some jurisdictions have laws that can pierce the corporate veil where control is being exercised improperly but in properly run companies with appropriate corporate governance there is no legal connection.

Comment: There is a fairly recent U.S. Supreme Court case that agrees with your answer. I'll try to find it if I have time.

Comment: Here it is *Goodyear Dunlop Tires Operations, S..A. v. Brown*, 564 U.S. 915 (2011).